# Read webserver logs: flow of pages

Tags: linux, open-source, python, logs, apache

I have Apache log files which include the `HTTP_REFERER`. I would like to analyse the flow of pages which were done by the user.

In detail the question is: I have log-file line X. Which log-file line is the correspoding previous line?

I would like to avoid to use regex myself, since I think this was solved by more intelligent developers before.

Is there a library or tool which helps here?

Required features:

- open source
- runs on Linux
- somehow scriptable via Python

Comment: If no library or Python but a tool, on what OS should it run? [Visitors](http://www.hping.org/visitors/) should at least partially fit your needs. A Debian package can be found [in my repository](https://apt.izzysoft.de/ubuntu/dists/generic/). Would that make an acceptable answer? Then let me know and I'll elaborate :)

Comment: @Izzy I wrote "runs on Linux" did you not read it, or do you mean something else with "on what Os should it run"?

Comment: Ouch, blindness – sorry, my bad. Then visitors definitely should be worth a try :) If it's a Debian based system, you can find a 64bit package on my site, as I wrote.